# How to get the schema name when we component source XML directly

Tags: tridion

I am working on creating components using core services 2011 in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

I just want to know, is it possible to get the schema name when I have component source XML directly in my local machine.

Consider i have ABCD.xml stored in my local machine. I want to give the this ABCD.xml as input get the schema that it is using.

Is it possible Via core services 2011, if yes please share your views on it.

Just to have a sample content xml file in my local machine. it is here.

```
            <Content xmlns="uuid:someUUID">
                 <first>first filed</first>
                 <second>second field</second>
            </Content>
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you are having trouble getting your code to work, I suggest you share your code. That way there's a better chance you'll get answers that you can immediately copy/paste into your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:
    XmlDocument componentXml = new XmlDocoment();

```
XmlDocument componentXml = new XmlDocument();
componentXml.Load("Your Xml File Path");
XmlNameTable nameTable = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");

XmlNode schemaNode = componentXml.SelectSingleNode("/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Schema", nsmgr);
string schemaTitle = schemaNode.Attributes["xlink:title"].Value;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error. at "error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at line 48. Line 47 and 48 are XmlNode schemaNode = componentXml.SelectSingleNode("/tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Schema", nsmgr);
string schemaTitle = schemaNode.Attributes["xlink:title"].Value;
Please look at it.

Comment: I have also added sample content file. plz check it.

Comment: From the content xml u can't figure out the Schema Title. U need the Component Xml.
You can get the Component Xml using Tom.Net Api. 

    Component comp = new Component("tcm:1-56", Session);
    XmlElement componentXml = comp.ToXml();

Or you can use protocol handler to retrive the component xml. if you type the tcm uri of the component in your browser [in CM Server] you will get the component xml in return.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, the XML of a Component contains the reference to the Schema TcmUri and title (under node `tcm:Component/tcm:Data/tcm:Schema`).

However, if you load the `ComponentData` in the Core Service, you won't see the full Component XML exposed through the `ComponentData` API.

There is a way to retrieve the Schema `TcmUri` and title from the `ComponentData`. Just use `ComponentData.Schema` properties `IdRef` or `Title`.